# rearrange the list map in Flutter

Tags: list, sqlite, flutter

I have a list map like below :

```
[
data{text: hello, date: 2020-09-11}, data{text: hi, date: 2020-09-12},
data{text: why, date: 2020-09-11}, data{text: how, date: 2020-09-10},
data{text: when, date: 2020-09-11}, data{text:flutter, date: 2020-09-12}
]
```

and what I want to get is this :

```
{
2020-09-10 : [how], 
2020-09-11 : [hello, why, when], 
2020-09-12 : [hi, flutter]
}
```

I'm a bit confusing between `list<map>` and `list` , I have no idea how to solve this.
I already know remove duplicate things with method `toSet().toList()`.
Is there any method related with this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

-------------------- **After following answer** -----------------------

date => createTime, text => repeat

```
 loadRepeat() async {
    DBHelperRepeat sd = DBHelperRepeat();
    var list = await sd.repeats();
    List newList = [];

    if (list[0].createTime == list[1].createTime) {
      newList.add({
        'date': list[0].createTime,
        'repeat': list[0].repeat + ',' + list[1].createTime
      });
    } else {
      newList.add({'date': list[0].createTime, 'repeat': list[0].repeat});
      newList.add({'date': list[1].createTime, 'repeat': list[1].repeat});
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i].createTime == newList.last.createTime) {
        newList.last.repeat += ',' + list[i].repeat;
      } else {
        newList.add(list[i]);
      }
    }
    print(newList);
  }
```

and here's my sqlite db code

**repeat.dart**

```
class Repeat {
  final String repeat;
  final String createTime;
  final int year;
  final int month;
  final int date;

  Repeat({this.repeat, this.createTime, this.year, this.month, this.date});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'repeat': repeat,
      'createTime': createTime,
      'year': year,
      'month': month,
      'date': date
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{repeat: $repeat, createTime: $createTime, year: $year, month: $month, date: $date}';
  }
}
```

**db_repeat.dart**

```
class DBHelperRepeat {
  var _db;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_db != null) return _db;
    _db = openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'repeats.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        return db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE repeats(repeat TEXT, createTime TEXT, year INT, month INT, date INT)",
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
    return _db;
  }

  Future<void> insertRepeat(Repeat repeat) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db.insert('repeats', repeat.toMap(),
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
  }

  Future<List<Repeat>> repeats() async {
    final db = await database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('repeats');

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Repeat(
          repeat: maps[i]['repeat'],
          createTime: maps[i]['createTime'],
          year: maps[i]['year'],
          month: maps[i]['month'],
          date: maps[i]['date']);
    });
  }
```

example data list:

```
[{repeat: repeat1, createTime: 2020-09-13, year: 2020, month: 9, date: 13}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
DBHelperRepeat sd = DBHelperRepeat();
List<Repeat> list = await sd.repeats();


list.sort((a,b)=> a.createTime.compareTo(b.createTime));


List<Repeat> newList = [];

if(list.length == 0){
      return newList;
    } else if(list.length == 1){
      newList.addAll(list);
      return newList;
    } 

    if (list[0].createTime == list[1].createTime) {
      newList.add(
        Repeat(
          createTime: list[0].createTime,
          repeat: list[0].repeat+', '+list[1].repeat,
          date: list[0].date, 
          month: list[0].month,
          year: list[0].year
        )
      );
    } else {
      newList.add(list[0]);
      newList.add(list[1]);
    }

   if(list.length < 3){
      return newList;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i].createTime == newList.last.createTime) {

        Repeat last = newList.last;
        Repeat repeat = Repeat(
          createTime: last.createTime,
          repeat: last.repeat+', ' + list[i].repeat,
          date: last.date, 
          month: last.month,
          year: last.year
        );
        newList.removeLast();
        newList.add(repeat);
      } else {
        newList.add(list[i]);
      }
    }
    newList.forEach((element) {
      print(element.createTime);
      print(element.repeat);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but I got error `NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' has no instance getter 'date'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:2
Tried calling: date)`. How can I solve this?

Comment: please provide the data type that you are using for your list, or an actual example list that you want to be rearranged.

Comment: edited my question with additional code for your understanding! please take a look.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect the modification in your question.

Comment: Could you explain why you use `List<Repeat>` instead of `List`? It returns error `The name 'Repeat' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'Repeat'.`

Comment: that is what ```await sd.repeats();``` returns from```Future<List<Repeat>> repeats() async {...}```. Make sure you have imported the ```repeat.dart```.

Comment: I forgot importing `repeat.dart`. Thanks a lot! It works like a charm!

Comment: I add comment to ask additional question. If I don't want sqlite for `newList`, how can I edit the code? Actually, I need `newList` without `date, month, year` and also, is it possible to replace the item 'createTime' from `String` to `DateTime`? I'd like to use this code for calendar widget, that's why I need the `DateTime`. ex) `{DateTime(2020, 09, 12) : ['repeat1', 'repeat2']}` Thanks in advance. You're a genius.

Comment: You can modify the ```Repeat``` class, change from ```String``` to ```DateTime``` and delete the unwanted fields, or if you still need the class as it is create a new class with the fields that you need and use the new class for ```newList```

Comment: And also if you need to get ```DateTime``` from ```String``` you can use the ```DateFormat().parse()``` from intl package, or just extract the year, month and day from the ```String```.

Comment: I've tried your code, and it worked, but different error came up. `RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)` I made a new question page to ask separately. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63894705/13564904 If you're available, I'll really appreciate it if you could solve the question.